# Uglify unable to work for nested if-else

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using [this online tool](https://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) to uglify my code although i'm using grunt-uglify to do the same but same error with this also, It works fine to minify the code but when i evaluate this code it returns an error of `expected :`. since it's not working for nested `if-else` case.

**Sample code.**

```
$._ext_ILST = {
    changeColorLabel: function() {
        spots = app.documents[0].spots;
        var colorLabelArray = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < spots.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (spots[i].toString() !== "[Spot]") {
                    if (spots[i].name.indexOf('$') == 0) {
                        colorLabelArray.push(spots[i].name.substring(1, spots[i].name.length));
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        var colorInfo = getColorInfromation();
        var obj = {}
        if (colorInfo.length > 0)
            colorLabelArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < colorInfo.length; i++) {
            colorLabelArray.push(colorInfo[i].colorName);
            if ((colorInfo[i].hasOwnProperty('colorType') && colorInfo[i].colorType != "teamColorVariable")) {
                if (colorInfo[i].isGarmentColor) {
                    obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "G"
                } else {
                    obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "D"
                }
            } else if (!colorInfo[i].hasOwnProperty('colorType')) {
                if (colorInfo[i].isGarmentColor) {
                    obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "G"
                } else {
                    obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "D"
                }
            }
        }
        var mainColorObj = {
            colorLabelArray: colorLabelArray,
            colorMapArray: obj
        }
        return JSON.stringify(mainColorObj);
    }
}
```

**Minified ouput -**

```
$._ext_ILST = {
    changeColorLabel: function() {
        spots = app.documents[0].spots;
        for (var a = new Array, b = 0; b < spots.length; b++) try {
            "[Spot]" !== spots[b].toString() && 0 == spots[b].name.indexOf("$") && a.push(spots[b].name.substring(1, spots[b].name.length))
        } catch (c) {}
        var d = getColorInfromation(),
            e = {};
        d.length > 0 && (a = []);
        for (var b = 0; b < d.length; b++) a.push(d[b].colorName), d[b].hasOwnProperty("colorType") && "teamColorVariable" != d[b].colorType ? d[b].isGarmentColor ? e[d[b].colorName] = "G" : e[d[b].colorName] = "D" : d[b].hasOwnProperty("colorType") || (d[b].isGarmentColor ? e[d[b].colorName] = "G" : e[d[b].colorName] = "D");
        var f = {
            colorLabelArray: a,
            colorMapArray: e
        };
        return JSON.stringify(f)
    }
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Upendra sengar

Answer (score 0):

You should [lint your JS first](http://jshint.com/).

Here’s a post-lint (and slightly modified) version of your code:

```
/* globals app, $, getColorInfromation */

(function(app, $, JSON, undefined) {
    $._ext_ILST = {
        changeColorLabel: function() {
            var spots = app.documents[0].spots;
            var colorLabelArray = [];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < spots.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (spots[i].toString() !== "[Spot]") {
                        if (spots[i].name.indexOf('$') === 0) {
                            colorLabelArray.push(spots[i].name.substring(1, spots[i].name.length));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e) {}
            }

            var colorInfo = getColorInfromation();
            var obj = {};
            if (colorInfo.length > 0)
                colorLabelArray = [];
            for (i = 0; i < colorInfo.length; i++) {
                colorLabelArray.push(colorInfo[i].colorName);
                if ((colorInfo[i].hasOwnProperty('colorType') && colorInfo[i].colorType != "teamColorVariable")) {
                    if (colorInfo[i].isGarmentColor) {
                        obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "G";
                    } else {
                        obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "D";
                    }
                } else if (!colorInfo[i].hasOwnProperty('colorType')) {
                    if (colorInfo[i].isGarmentColor) {
                        obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "G";
                    } else {
                        obj[colorInfo[i].colorName] = "D";
                    }
                }
            }
            var mainColorObj = {
                colorLabelArray: colorLabelArray,
                colorMapArray: obj
            };
            return JSON.stringify(mainColorObj);
        }
    };
}(app, $, JSON));
```

Note that I [wrapped your code in an IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to give you better uglification results. Also notice that I only did a topical sweeping of your code … there’s more that I think you could do to make it better (e.g., brackets around `if` statements, I personally like to explicitly [hoist all my vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), etc.).

Next, I quickly googled for an [online minification/uglification tool](http://jscompress.com/) and copy/pasted the linted version of your code; here’s the result:

```
!function(o,r,e,a){r._ext_ILST={changeColorLabel:function(){var r,a=o.documents[0].spots,n=[];for(r=0;r<a.length;r++)try{"[Spot]"!==a[r].toString()&&0===a[r].name.indexOf("$")&&n.push(a[r].name.substring(1,a[r].name.length))}catch(t){}var l=getColorInfromation(),c={};for(l.length>0&&(n=[]),r=0;r<l.length;r++)n.push(l[r].colorName),l[r].hasOwnProperty("colorType")&&"teamColorVariable"!=l[r].colorType?l[r].isGarmentColor?c[l[r].colorName]="G":c[l[r].colorName]="D":l[r].hasOwnProperty("colorType")||(l[r].isGarmentColor?c[l[r].colorName]="G":c[l[r].colorName]="D");var m={colorLabelArray:n,colorMapArray:c};return e.stringify(m)}}}(app,$,JSON);
```

Not sure if that’s what you’re looking for, and/or if the code still functions, but hopefully that puts you in the right direction?